# Checking room availability

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, logic

Here is the code, if the user adds an event on that room at 7:00AM-12:00NN. So it should be unavailable at that time, but my code only reads the starting time and the ending time, any suggestions?

```
public bool checkSched(string start, string endtime, string room, string day)
{

    myCon.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    bool found = false;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Subject WHERE (Starting_Time=@start OR Ending_Time = @endtime) AND (Room = @room) AND (Day=@day)", myCon);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = start;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@room", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = room;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@day", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = day;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@endtime", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = endtime;

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    found = dr.HasRows;
    myCon.Close();
    return found;
}
```

Comment: it's available at 8:00AM - 11:00AM.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1054236-338-1.aspx

Comment: Little hint: you want to know which room is available _between_ starttime and end time.

Comment: how do you determine, a room is available or taken??

Comment: I have a database that says that room is taken at this time, i.e 7:00AM-12:00NN, but when i add another event for that room which is 8:00AM- 11:00AM, its says it's available.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, if I undertand your intention correctly, but If you want to check if there any event overlapping between `@start` and `@endtime`, you should use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM Subject WHERE (
(Starting_Time BETWEEN @start AND @endtime) 
OR 
(Ending_Time BETWEEN @start AND @endtime)
) AND (Room = @room) AND (Day=@day)
```

See [`BETWEEN` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) for understanding `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Hey it works, i'm new to sql and i have tons to do. thanks for your answer.

Comment: +1 for taking into account the case of existing time-spans that *end* during the requested slot. Would have up-voted twice if I could for pointing to BETWEEN :)

Comment: Jan Darren Noroña: I'm glad it helped, please, take a carefull look at how BETWEEN handles edge condition (when start time is exactly the same as one of the arguments) and if this way of handling is OK with your intention). BTW, mark the answer as accepted, so people with the same problem see the resolution.

Comment: @spender : I know, I know, but ot looks like TS is quite new to SQL in which case w3school is a very good hands-on resource to read. You can't start from Relational algebra in case you don't have a year to learn how BETWEEN works :)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to cast your sql result string for the start and the end time to a DateTime type.

```
 //start and end time from the room stored in the DB
 DateTime startTimeDB;
 DateTime endTimeDB;

 DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out startTime)
 DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out endTime)
```

check this link for further information: [MSDN DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

You are also using strings in you method parameters for the start and end time, is it possible to use DateTime type there? Otherwise you also need to parse the parameter strings into DateTime objects:

```
 //start and end time for your new event
 DateTime startTimeNew;
 DateTime endTimeNew;

 DateTime.TryParse(start, out startTimeNew)
 DateTime.TryParse(endtime, out endTimeNew)
```

After try something like this:

```
if (startTimeNew.Ticks > startTime.Ticks && endTimeNew.Ticks < endTime.Ticks)
{
    return false;
}
return true
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a room which is occupied between start time and end time. Easiest is to check if start time is between any Starting_Time and Ending_Time.

```
Starting_Time < @start AND Ending_Time > @start
```

But thats only the half job. You also want room which are booked and end between @start and @end (or even later). I think you can figure out the extra case for this.

Note: make Starting_Time and Ending_Time dates in your database.